# TypeError: SpeechRecognition is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I am programming a game with React, TypeScript by using the Web Speech API. I use **SpeechRecognition** and **SpeechSynthesisUtterance** there is no problem with that but when I test the code with jest I get some type and reference errors like this:

**TypeError: SpeechRecognition is not a constructor**

and this one

**ReferenceError: SpeechSynthesisUtterance is not defined**

here is the code

```
const SpeechRecognition = (window as any).SpeechRecognition || (window as any).webkitSpeechRecognition;

const recognition: any = new SpeechRecognition();
```

and that is how I use the other api

```
const utter: any = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(newSelection);

utter.lang = 'tr-TR';
```

as I said before, app runs correctly but when I test it got this errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's OK. When you do testing, your runtime doesn't support SpeechRecognition object. It doesn't have it. To fix the issue you must use it only after checking for existence, like here:

```
if ('SpeechRecognition' in window) {
    const x = new SpeechRecognition();
}
```

However, this is not the best approach, it's repetitive. I would advise creating the simple class that would wrap SpeechRecognition object inside himself and do this checking.

Something like this:

```
class MySpeechRecognizer {
    private readonly _instance: SpeechRecognition | undefined;
    constructor() {
        if ('SpeechRecognition' in window) { this._instance = new SpeechRecognition() }
    }

    start() {
        if (this._instance) {
            this._instance.start()
        }
    }
}
```